# How to use $elemMatch on an embedded array using jenssegers/laravel-mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

My document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5824a9472e94e0995d3b0f0c"),
    "full_name" : "Kelly Denise Benavides",
    "aliases" : [ 
        "Kelly D Benavides", 
        "Kelly Benavides"
    ]
}
```

I am wanting to search the document and return the document if user enters 'Kelly D Benavides'. I have tried using:

```
$person = Person::where('aliases', 'Kelly D Benavides')->first();
```

I believe the correct way to do so is using elemMatch but not clear on the syntax. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method #01

```
db.collection.find(
   { aliases: { $elemMatch: { "Kelly D Benavides" } } }
)
```

Method #02

```
db.collection.find({"aliases":{$elemMatch:{"$in":["Kelly D Benavides"], "$exists":true}}})


Person::where('aliases', 'elemMatch', array('Kelly D Benavides'))->first();

Person::where('aliases', 'all', ['Kelly D Benavides'])->first();
```

Comment: Thanks. The db.collection.find({"aliases":{$elemMatch:{"$in":["Kelly D Benavides"], "$exists":true}}}) works great. However when I try doing Person::where('aliases', 'elemMatch', array('Kelly D Benavides'))->first(); it says '$elemMatch needs an Object'

Answer (score -1):

This code will work fine for you:

```
$person = Person::where('aliases', 'elemMatch', ['$eq' => 'Kelly D Benavides'])->first();
```